# Call generic method with Expression through reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, reflection

I have a generic method which should return the last record from a table:

```
public T FindLast<TKey>(Expression<Func<T,TKey>> specification = null)
{
    return specification == null
        ? Set().LastOrDefault()
        : Set().OrderBy(specification).LastOrDefault();
}
```

I need to call it through reflection

```
var methodCreateReadRepositoryAttr = (entityMetadata.GetEntityAttributeType() != null) ? 
typeof(IRepositoryFactory).GetMethod("CreateReadRepository").MakeGenericMethod(entityMetadata.GetEntityAttributeType()) : null;

var methodEntityGet3 = attributeReadRepository.GetType().GetMethod("FindLast", new Type[] { typeof(Expression<Func<ArticleAttribute,int>>) });
```

But in debug `methodEntityGet3` is null. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you able to call it without reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break your method calling in to two:

```
var methodEntityGet3 = attributeReadRepository.GetType().GetMethod("FindLast");
var closedGenericMethod = methodEntity3.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeof(Expression<Func<ArticleAttribute,int>>) };
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are requesting a method with the closed type, meanwhile the method `FindLast` is generic and has an open type, i.e., the type of the parameter is `Expression<Func<T, TKey>>` and not the type you provided. The reflection system will not go and create the generic method that fits best, as this may depend on what the rules in the language are. You may achive that converting the arguments to `dynamic`, but I am not exactly sure about that.

Furthermore, there is no easy way to get the type parameters `T` and `TKey`, so I would suggest you search the method only with its name and then explicitly create the generic method below, like you did for the method above.

**Edit:** Actually, the `dynamic` solution actually works and is probably much more readable than any reflection call can be. The following code compiles and outputs what can be expected:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo<string>();
        Expression<Func<string, int>> arg = s => s.Length;
        CallFindLast(foo, arg);
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void CallFindLast(Foo<string> foo, object arg)
    {
        var dynamicArg = (dynamic)arg;
        foo.FindLast(dynamicArg);
    }

    private class Foo<T>
    {
        public T FindLast<TKey>(Expression<Func<T, TKey>> specification = null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"T: {typeof(T).Name}, TKey: {typeof(TKey).Name}");
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```