# Call metthod with Expression through reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, reflection

I call method with Expression, which return last record in table :

```
   public T FindLast<TKey>(Expression<Func<T,TKey>> specification = null)
{
    return specification == null
        ? Set().LastOrDefault()
        : Set().OrderBy(specification).LastOrDefault();
}
```

through reflection

```
 var methodCreateReadRepositoryAttr = (entityMetadata.GetEntityAttributeType() != null) ? 
typeof(IRepositoryFactory).GetMethod("CreateReadRepository").MakeGenericMethod(entityMetadata.GetEntityAttributeType()) : null;

    var methodEntityGet3 = attributeReadRepository.GetType().GetMethod("FindLast");
var closedGenericMethod = methodEntity3.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeof(Expression<Func<ArticleAttribute,int>>) };

Expression <Func<ArticleAttribute, int>> articleReturnExpression = e => e.ArticleAttributeID;   

 var fromRepo3 = closedGenericMethod.Invoke(attributeReadRepository, new object[] {articleReturnExpression});
```

On the last line I have error message

> Object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[RRP.Framework.Domain.Entities.ArticleAttribute,System.Int32]]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[RRP.Framework.Domain.Entities.ArticleAttribute,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[RRP.Framework.Domain.Entities.ArticleAttribute,System.Int32]]]]'.

Comment: How is this different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40737230/call-generic-method-with-expression-through-reflection?

Comment: This is next problem that apear. Sorry!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so that you can get an answer which we can *show* working, all the way. It doesn't help anyone to solve one tiny bit of a problem at a time, when with a complete example we can give a complete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the generic argument type with method argument type.

The only generic argument of your method

```
public T FindLast<TKey>(Expression<Func<T,TKey>> specification = null)
```

is `TKey`.  Hence

```
var closedGenericMethod = methodEntity3.MakeGenericMethod(
    new Type[] { typeof(Expression<Func<ArticleAttribute,int>>) });
```

should be

```
var closedGenericMethod = methodEntity3.MakeGenericMethod(
    new Type[] { typeof(int) });
```